# ¿si paso por parametro un variable en $scope a un servicio, si se modifica en el servicio, no se modifica en el controlador?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, servicio, angularjs-scope

Buenas,

Estoy haciendo este procedimiento y tengo una duda, estoy pasando unas serie de paramentos a un servicio, que en el modifico esas variables que van por parámetro, luego al acceder en el controlador, no veo los cambios, ojo esto pasa nada mas con variables que no son array, dejo el codigo:

Controlador:

```
gridService.potitionInitial($scope.grids, $scope.posXAct, $scope.posYAct);
```

Servicio:

```
this.potitionInitial =  function (grid, posXAct, posYAct) {   
                posXAct = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                posYAct = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                grid[posXAct][posYAct].active = true;
            }
```

El $scope.grid si se modifica, pero el $scope.posXAct y $scope.porYAct no, realmente no entiendo porque los array si se pasan por referencia y las variables normales no, por favor ayudenme, necesito con urgencia resolver esto.

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando pasas una variable como parametro a una function se pasa por valor(by value) pero cuando es un objeto se pasa por referencia pero ***solo a las propiedades del objeto se les puede modificar***.

[Ejemplo](http://jsbin.com/pocorexape/edit?js,console):

```
function prueba(a, b)
{
  a.b = "adios";
  b.c = "adios";
  a = null;
}

var a = {
  b : "hola"
};

var b = {
  c : "hola"
};

prueba(a,b);

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

Imprime:

```
[object Object] {
  b: "adios"
}
[object Object] {
  c: "adios"
}
```

Si te fijas las propiedades internas si fueron modificadas pero no el objeto como tal como paso con `a = null`. El objeto `a` sigue teniendo su propiedad aunque el asignamos null al final de la funcion.